# Read custom settings of Office documents through Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js

Can I read and write custom attributes of Office documents through Microsoft Graph?

I'm setting custom attributes in my Office Addin via [`Office.context.document.settings.get()`](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/shared/document.settings.md) and would like to read those using Microsoft Graph without having users to open a file and use the add-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something supported by Microsoft Graph directly.

You could download a copy of the document, unpack it (Office documents are a zip archive) and then parse the OOXML directly. [Settings are not encrypted](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/docs/develop/persisting-add-in-state-and-settings.md) so it shouldn't be to challenging parse them out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and confirming that it is not possible as of today